# Second derivative of matrix inverse

Tags: matrices, derivatives, partial-derivative

Let $A \colon \mathbb R^d \to \mathbb R^{n\times n}$ be a matrix-valued function of vectorial input, and assume that $A(x)$ is always invertible. I want to compute
$$
\partial_{ij}{A^{-1}} = \frac{\partial^2 (A^{-1})}{\partial x_i\partial x_j}.
$$
For the first derivative, I apply
$$
\partial_i (A^{-1}A)=0,
$$
to obtain
$$
\partial_iA^{-1}=-A^{-1}(\partial_iA) A^{-1}.
$$
Deriving the right-hand side with respect to $x_j$ with the product rule, I obtain
$$\tag{1}
\partial_{ij}A^{-1}=-(\partial_jA^{-1})(\partial_i A)A^{-1}-A^{1}(\partial_{ij} A)A^{-1}-A^{-1}(\partial_i A)(\partial_jA^{-1}).
$$
If instead I start from
$$
\partial_{ij}(A^{-1}A)=0,
$$
derive first w.r.t. $x_i$ and then with respect to $x_j$, I obtain a different expression:
$$\tag{2}
\partial_{ij}A^{-1}=-(\partial_jA^{-1})(\partial_i A)A^{-1}-A^{-1}(\partial_{ij} A)A^{-1}-(\partial_i A^{-1})(\partial_j A)A^{-1}.
$$
Which is correct between (1) and (2), and why?$

**Edit: steps to get to (2)**

Differentiating with respect to $x_i$
$$
\partial_j ((\partial_iA^{-1})A + A^{-1}\partial_i A)=0,
$$
Differentiating with respect to $x_j$
$$
(\partial_{ij}A^{-1})A+(\partial_iA^{-1})(\partial_jA)+(\partial_jA^{-1})(\partial_iA)+A^{-1}(\partial_{ij}A)=0.
$$
Now bringing all terms but the first and multiplying by $A^{-1}$ on the right gives (2).

Comment: You probably did a mistake in your second attempt. Can you detail it in the question ?

Comment: There was a minor mistake, and I added how I get there. Probably there's still a mistake I can't see, or (1) and (2) are equivalent

Comment: They are actually equivalent

Comment: The second derivative  can be reduced to 
$$\large\eqalign{
\def\p{\partial}
\def\A{A^{-1}}
\p_{ij}A^{-1}
 &= \A\Big((\p_iA)\A(\p_jA)+(\p_jA)\A(\p_iA)-\p_{ij}A\Big)\A \\
}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) and (2) are equivalent. Using twice the formula for the first derivative on the third term on the right-hand side of (2), we have
\begin{align}
(\partial_i A^{-1})(\partial_j A) A^{-1} &= -A^{-1}(\partial_i A)A^{-1}(\partial_j A) A^{-1} \\
&= -A^{-1}(\partial_i A)(\partial_j A^{-1}),
\end{align}
which is the third term at the right-hand side of (1). The first and second terms coincide.